# Extend Catalina's privacy protection to other folders

Tags: macos, permission, catalina, privacy

In MacOS Catalina apps need to ask for explicit permission to access certain user folders (such as ~/Documents and ~/Downloads).

Is it possible to extend this protection to other folders (e.g. a custom user-created folder ~/foo) without moving it inside the Documents folder?

Answer (score 1):

No.

The restricted file locations are detailed here [PrivacyPreferencesPolicyControl.Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/privacypreferencespolicycontrol/services) and you can't change them.

You would have to move `~/foo` to Documents, Downloads, an external drive, or another restricted location.